# Parsing boolean expression without left hand recursion

Tags: parsing, grammar, peg, pegjs

I'm trying to match this

```
f(some_thing) == 'something else'
```

- **f(some_thing)** is a function call, which is an expression
- **==** is a boolean operator
- **'something else'** is a string, which also is an expression

so the boolean expression should be

```
expression operator expression
```

The problem is I can't figure out how to do that without left recursion
These are my rules

```
expression 
  = 
  bool_expression
  / function_call
  / string
  / real_number
  / integer
  / identifier

bool_expression
  = l:expression space* op:bool_operator space* r:expression 
  { return ... }
```

Using grammar notation, I have

```
O := ==|<=|>=|<|>|!=  // operators
E := B|....           // expression, many non terminals
B := EOE
```

Because my grammar is EOE I don't know how to use the left hand algorithm which is

```
A := Ab|B
transforms into
A := BA'
A':= e|bA
```

Where e is empty and b is a terminal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this ought to do it:

```
expression
 = bool_expression

bool_expression
 = add_expression "==" bool_expression
 / add_expression "!=" bool_expression
 / add_expression

add_expression
 = mult_expression "+" add_expression
 / mult_expression "-" add_expression
 / mult_expression

mult_expression
 = atom "*" mult_expression
 / atom "/" mult_expression
 / atom

atom
 = function_call 
 / string
 / real_number
 / integer
 / identifier

function_call
 = identifier "(" (expression ("," expression)*)? ")"

string
 = "'" [^']* "'"

identifier
 = [a-zA-Z_]+

integer
 = [0-9]+

real_number
 = integer "." integer?
 / "." integer
```

Comment: Thank you good sir, that works! I did find out before this answer how to do it, and was about to post it, but you did an awesome job :P